# What is the use of adding an exception to a method of a global class?

Tags: exception, abap

So, I added this image, hoping it would help :
[image: Method exception]

My question is: What is the point of doing this? I have created my global exception class(with my own messages), I have raised it in a method of a global class and I have also caught this exception - and I have done all these without giving that particular method the exception, so does it help in any way to give a method exceptions?

Short update, this is my method code:
[image: Method code]

A coworker told me to give the method an exception parameter instead of writing the code from picture 2. If I do so, I don't see any changes and this is why I do not see the point of doing what is in the first picture.

Comment: Classical exceptions and oo-based exception classes are not usable together in parallel in all cases. That's, why I would recommend Your way. Nevertheless, You raise Your exception AND catch it inside one method. This is simple and indeed it is not really necessary in here, (but in terms of propagating the exception upwards the callstack, this makes more sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question. Because of the overhead, such exceptions create either by creating them, adding them, linking them to a message-class and throwing/catching them, it really, also for me, seems sometimes a kind of "shooting rockets at birds". Most things can really be caught by catching `CX_ROOT`.
Nevertheless there are really cases, where it is important to distinguish between exceptions, and therefore it is a nice-oop-standard to create some own, 
If:

- the exception's class type/meaning cannot be covered by the abap-standard exceptions
- the exception class should be linked against own message-class-messages
- the exception class should provide special features like "resumable".

In the end this question is some kind of "best practice/best usecase" question and I also would be glad to see some other answers, which can pinpoint to other points of view about this topic.

Comment: So, I added more context to the question. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: -1. Catching CX_ROOT is a really really bad idea. You'll end up swallowing error conditions that you have no way of handling, and probably suppressing error messages and/or short dumps that you would really want to occur. In case of a severe inconsistency, would you really want to have your program continue as if the (unanticipated!) exception never happened?

Comment: Vwegwert: I did not mean to swallow any exceptions and/or error conditions. I see sap Standard catching cx_root also very often. In deed it is also possible to distinguish, which exception it was, because you can determine it inside the catch. As a point of Software design, I also appreciate, not to dump, at all.

Answer (score 2):

To refer to your original question: Adding the exception to the **signature** of your method simply states that the method might throw that exception (which makes sense for dynamically checked exceptions and is required for statically checked exceptions, to keep things simple). This is of little use for the method implementation (besides the fact that it makes raising an exception without errors possible), but it is an important message to the caller: When calling method FOO, be aware that ZCX_BAR might occur - deal with it or ignore it at your own peril.

Comment: That is, what I meant with "pinpoint to other opinions". Thanks. Perhaps some other People might join this.